# Permission denied issue while doing CD even after having group permission

Tags: linux, permissions, cd-command, ldap

I'm getting `Permission denied` while doing a `cd` into directory  `/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1` and user is a member of this group; other users on the group can easily accessing the files but only this user can not. Below is a snipped output of the `strace` from the user's home dir..

```
 Prod- > strace csh -c 'cd /tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1'
    execve("/bin/csh", ["csh", "-c", "cd /tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cu"...], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
    brk(0)                                  = 0xb2a000
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0dd0ef2000
    access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
    open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 26, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0dd0ef1000
    close(3)                                = 0
    open("/dgagent/lib64/preload.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0(\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=25895, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2115192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0dd0acf000
    mprotect(0x7f0dd0ad4000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7f0dd0cd3000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7f0dd0cd3000
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7f0dd0ef1000, 26)              = 0
    open("/grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v4.8.3/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v4.8.3/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v4.8.3/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
    open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3

    open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26060, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 26060, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7f0dd0edf000
    close(3)                                = 0
    gettimeofday({1550755896, 639009}, NULL) = 0
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 1999}, ...}) = 0
    getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 0}, ...}) = 0
    open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY)             = 3
    close(3)                                = 0
    getuid()                                = 34400
    getgid()                                = 1001
    geteuid()                               = 34400
    getegid()                               = 1001
    gettimeofday({1550755896, 640019}, NULL) = 0
    dup2(0, 16)                             = 16
    fcntl(16, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
    dup2(1, 17)                             = 17
    fcntl(17, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
    dup2(2, 18)                             = 18
    fcntl(18, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
    dup2(16, 19)                            = 19
    fcntl(19, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
    ioctl(18, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    ioctl(17, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    ioctl(16, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    readlink("/proc/self/fd/16", "/dev/pts/5"..., 4095) = 10
    rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x4439d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0dd03156a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], NULL, 8) = 0
    getcwd("/home/myuser", 4096)           = 14
    stat("/home/myuser", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
    stat("/home/myuser", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
    uname({sys="Linux", node="sj-myuser", ...}) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0dd03156a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
    dup(3)                                  = 5
    dup(5)                                  = 6
    close(5)                                = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
    dup(4)                                  = 3
    dup(3)                                  = 5
    dup(5)                                  = 7
    close(5)                                = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
    clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0dd0e969d0) = 5257
    socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
    connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = 0
    sendto(3, "\2\0\0\0\v\0\0\0\7\0\0\0passwd\0", 19, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 19
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
    recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"bin/xae", 7}, {"\30m\30\31\377\177\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
    connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = 0
    sendto(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0nanosrc\0", 20, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 20
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
    read(3, "\2\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\351\\\0\0\222u\0\0\10\0\0\0\16\0\0\0"..., 36) = 36
    read(3, "nanosrc\0x\0Nanosrc\0/home/nanosrc\0"..., 41) = 41
    fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
    clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0dd0e969d0) = 5290
    gettimeofday({1550755896, 842153}, NULL) = 0
    close(9)                                = 0
    read(8, "2\n", 4096)                    = 2
    --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
    rt_sigreturn(0x11)                      = 2
    wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, {ru_utime={0, 999}, ru_stime={0, 0}, ...}) = 5290
    wait4(-1, 0x7fff19181af0, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, 0x7fff19181a60) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
    read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(8)                                = 0

    lstat("so", 0x7fff19186c20)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    close(0)                                = 0
    close(1)                                = 0
    close(2)                                = 0
    alarm(0)                                = 0
    alarm(0)                                = 0
    close(0)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    dup(19)                                 = 0
    fcntl(0, F_SETFD, 0)                    = 0
    close(1)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    dup(17)                                 = 1
    fcntl(1, F_SETFD, 0)                    = 0
    close(2)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    dup(18)                                 = 2
    fcntl(2, F_SETFD, 0)                    = 0
    dup(18)                                 = 2
    fcntl(2, F_SETFD, 0)                    = 0
    chdir("/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1") = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
    chdir("/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1") = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
    open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2512, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0dd0ede000
    read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2512
    read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7f0dd0ede000, 4096)            = 0
    open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    write(2, "/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_"..., 74/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1: Permission denied.
    ) = 74
    lseek(16, 0, SEEK_END)                  = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
    fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 5), ...}) = 0
    close(0)                                = 0
    fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 5), ...}) = 0
    close(1)                                = 0
    fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 5), ...}) = 0
    close(2)                                = 0
    fstat(3, 0x7fff19189d10)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(94, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(95, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(96, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(97, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(98, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(99, 0x7fff19189d10)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(207, 0x7fff19189d10)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(208, 0x7fff19189d10)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(209, 0x7fff19189d10)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    fstat(210, 0x7fff19189d10)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

    fstat(255, 0x7fff19189d10)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

As being a Linux Admin I have added more than 3 users, all are fine, but this particular user is having a problem.

Groups are maintained by LDAP, so the group in LDAP group for all.

Comment: What are the permissions of all directories up to `/tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1`? What does `id` print?

Comment: So, permissions of all directories up to  are `drwxr-xr-x` and group is same.

Comment: Don't describe the output with your own words, show the exact output of `ls -ld /tct`, , `ls -ld /tct/foxprod_t2b_002`, ... , `ls -ld /tct/foxprod_t2b_002/cilin/cust_test/testcases/level1` and `id`. If you overlooked an error, someone else may see it. If everything is correct, we know that it must be something else.  **Edit your question** and copy/paste the commands and their output to show additional information instead of writing comments.

Comment: @Bodo, I can not provide the listing of  the data due to security  compliance, I understand that and i'm not a user , I understand the nitty gritty as being a Linux admin , user may lie but I see that issue evidently happening for the user only while I have added other user in the group at the same time those don't have issues, and yes I replied on the comment because you asked!

Comment: Of course you should reply, but if additional information is necessary you should add this to the question instead of writing a comment. Comments are for critics, the important information should be in the question or in the answers.

Comment: You didn't say, so we have to assume -- did the user log out & back in to get their new group set?

Comment: Is it an NFS mount, and is the problematic user a member of more than 16 groups?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes in our environment we have everything ported and NFS and yes user is member of more than 16 group

Comment: Then you might be hitting this: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/17372

Comment: @JeffSchaller, thnx for the update I saw that , however I have opned a case lets see when they comes across.